# users and persmissions in a new VPS

Tags: permissions, ssh, sftp, vps

I have root user and a "domain" user for the virtual server/domain/site in the VPS. I'm going to disallow root access to SSH, meaning SFTP won't work as well.

I want to be able to view logs using sftp. root won't help me because it won't be able to login. "domain" user won't help me because it won't have permissions.

Is it possible to give a "sudo" permissions for the "domain" user when he logs into SFTP?

Is there another way to achieve what I want except for re-enabling root user?

Thanks

Comment: If you disallow root user than how can you manage other things.

Comment: While setup I do that with root, once I'm done, I want to disallow its access. I read an article on how to protect a VPS and that was one of the things there. I understand correctly that eventually, only root can do that and there is no way to give such permissions to other user that connects through sftp?

Comment: Yup, you can create another user sftp/ssh. Go through this link it will help you https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-a-user-account-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: I added a user and gave it sudo privs and it works great in ssh itself, but I understand that with SFTP it can be done.

Comment: You can also access ssh user with sftp.Please upvote the comment.

Comment: though it's not answering my question of having a sudo inside sftp.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more it will help me to answer.

Comment: I rephrased the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Please go through this link it will you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111026/how-to-use-sftp-on-a-system-that-requires-sudo-for-root-access-ssh-key-based-a/478602